# File.Exists and SpreadsheetDocument.Open returning File Not Found Exception in UWP Application

Tags: c#, uwp, system.io.file

Im having an issue with using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open` is not opening a spreadsheet, it returns a file not found exception. The class i'm using has worked many times before, but i've never used it in a UWP project.

I've created a simple example and found that I get the same issue when using `File.Exists` i've include all the `using` statements i use if that helps.

Does anyone know why the `File.Exists` cannot detect the file?
and yes i've triple checked the file does exist on D:!

**C# UWP Project created using UWP Template Studio [MainPage.xaml.cs]**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

using UWP_APP.ViewModels;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UWP_APP.Views
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string filePath = @"D:\example.xlsm";
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                int a = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int a = 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: It could be a permission problem 
Make sure to run as administrator (while debugging to rule that out);
It could be hiding file endings in windows
Make sure your file name is correct and no extension is hidden.

Comment: You might find the answers to [Access C Drive files in UWP AppService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873024/access-c-drive-files-in-uwp-appservice) useful.

Comment: Any updates for this thread? does the following work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the File.Exists cannot detect the file?

UWP app is running in sandbox, because `File.Exists` is `System.IO` api. So it could not work for accessing file except `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. If you do want to check if the file exist in the specific path, we suggest you add [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) capability and enable in the system file access setting. This capability works for APIs in the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

And using the flolowing method to check if the file exist.

```
try
{
    var file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\Karan\OneDrive\Desktop\2010.pdf");
    if (file != null)
    {
        isExist = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    isExist = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks yes this was effectively the issue i had -  it stems from the fact that you need the users permission to access all but some specific folders like ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.